# Cocoa/OSX - NSWindow standardWindowButton behaving strangely once copied and added again

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsbutton

In my app I change the position of the standardWindowButtons close / miniturize / expand like so:

```
 //Create the buttons
    NSButton *minitButton = [NSWindow standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton forStyleMask:window.styleMask];
NSButton *closeButton = [NSWindow standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton forStyleMask:window.styleMask];
NSButton *fullScreenButton = [NSWindow standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton forStyleMask:window.styleMask];


//set their location
[closeButton setFrame:CGRectMake(7+70, window.frame.size.height - 22 - 52, closeButton.frame.size.width, closeButton.frame.size.height)];
[fullScreenButton setFrame:CGRectMake(47+70, window.frame.size.height - 22 -52, fullScreenButton.frame.size.width, fullScreenButton.frame.size.height)];
[minitButton setFrame:CGRectMake(27+70, window.frame.size.height - 22 - 52, minitButton.frame.size.width, minitButton.frame.size.height)];

//add them to the window
[window.contentView addSubview:closeButton];
[window.contentView addSubview:fullScreenButton];
[window.contentView addSubview:minitButton];
```

Now when the window appears with the buttons there is two problems:
1. They are grey and not their correct color
2. when the mouse is over them they do not show the + - or x sign

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the mechanics of this hover magic: Before drawing itself standard circled button (such as `NSWindowMiniaturizeButton`) calls their `superview` undocumented method `_mouseInGroup:`. If this method returns `YES` circled button draws itself with icon inside. That's all.

If you place these buttons inside your own view, you can simply implement this method and control this mouse-hover-appearance as you want. If you just move or relayout these buttons and they still be `subview`s of `NSThemeFrame` (or something similar), you have to swizzle method `_mouseInGroup:` for this class, and probably it doesn't worth it because we have perfectly simple previous method.

In my case I have custom `NSView` that contains my standard buttons as `subview`s and this code makes all described above magic:

```
- (void)updateTrackingAreas
{
    NSTrackingArea *const trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:NSZeroRect options:(NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways | NSTrackingInVisibleRect) owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [super mouseEntered:event];
    self.mouseInside = YES;
    [self setNeedsDisplayForStandardWindowButtons];
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [super mouseExited:event];
    self.mouseInside = NO;
    [self setNeedsDisplayForStandardWindowButtons];
}

- (BOOL)_mouseInGroup:(NSButton *)button
{
    return self.mouseInside;
}

- (void)setNeedsDisplayForStandardWindowButtons
{
    [self.closeButtonView setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.miniaturizeButtonView setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.zoomButtonView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: @LiFumin You probably need to mark _mouseInGroup method as '@objc'.

Comment: `@objc func _mouseInGroup(_ : Any) -> Bool` in Swift.`

Answer (score 2):

I'm fully aware that this question is *old* and [**Valentin Shergin**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30417372/3642077) is **correct**. It prevents the utilize of any **Private API**, unlike [Google did in Chrome](https://src.chromium.org/svn/branches/324/src/chrome/browser/cocoa/browser_frame_view.mm). Just wanted to share a method for those who don't feel like subclass `NSView` just to put those buttons in an existed view (such as `self.window.contentView`).

As I just wanted to reposition the `NSWindowButton`s via `setFrame:`, I found out that once the window was **resized**, the tracking areas seems to "*fix*" themselves *automagically*, *without any Private API usage* (at least in 10.11).

Thus, you can do things like the following to apply "*fake resize*" to the window that you repositioned your buttons:

```
NSRect frame = [self.window frame];
frame.size = NSMakeSize(frame.size.width, frame.size.height+1.f);
[self.window setFrame:frame display:NO animate:NO];
frame.size = NSMakeSize(frame.size.width, frame.size.height-1.f);
[self.window setFrame:frame display:NO animate:YES];
```

(I did it within my main window's `NSWindowDelegate` `windowDidBecomeMain:`. Should work as long as the window is loaded and *visible*.)

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding them again. You're moving them to contentView. The buttons are originally in window.contentView.superview.

```
[window.contentView.superview addSubview:closeButton];
[window.contentView.superview addSubview:fullScreenButton];
[window.contentView.superview addSubview:minitButton];
```

Should get you the correct behaviour without requiring a trackingArea.

Answer (score 0):

After all this time, [Valentin Shergin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30417372/1347529) is still valid!

Updating for Swift 5.9, and adding hooks to redraw the buttons with the appropriate colors when the window gains or loses focus:

```
// Need to first add your traffic light buttons to this stack view
class FauxTitleBarView: NSStackView {
  var isMouseInside: Bool = false

  @objc func _mouseInGroup(_ button: NSButton) -> Bool {
    return isMouseInside
  }

  func markButtonsDirty() {
    for btn in views {
      btn.needsDisplay = true
    }
  }

  override func mouseEntered(with event: NSEvent) {
    isMouseInside = true
    markButtonsDirty()
  }

  override func mouseExited(with event: NSEvent) {
    isMouseInside = false
    markButtonsDirty()
  }
}

class MyWindowController: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {
  var fauxTitleBar: FauxTitleBarView? = nil

  func windowDidLoad() {
    let btnTypes: [NSWindow.ButtonType] = [.closeButton, .miniaturizeButton, .zoomButton]
    let trafficLightButtons: [NSButton] = btnTypes.compactMap{ NSWindow.standardWindowButton($0, for: .titled) }

    fauxTitleBar = FauxTitleBarView(views: trafficLightButtons)

    // ...

    for btn in trafficLightButtons {
      btn.addTrackingArea(NSTrackingArea(rect: btn.bounds, options: [.activeAlways, .inVisibleRect, .mouseEnteredAndExited], owner: fauxTitleBar, userInfo: nil))
    }
  }

  func windowDidBecomeMain(_ notification: Notification) {
    // The traffic light buttons should change to active color
    fauxTitleBar?.markButtonsDirty()
  }

  func windowDidResignMain(_ notification: Notification) {
    // The traffic light buttons should change to inactive color
    fauxTitleBar?.markButtonsDirty()
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Call `[button highlight:yes]` for each button.

Comment: Sadly `[button highlight:YES]` only draws the window button's "pressed" state ([reference](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/76398-standardwindowbuttons.html)). I don't know of a way yet to draw the "hover" state.