# Reposition NSWindowButton: trackingAreas incorrect/not updated unless window resized

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I was trying to reposition the `NSWindowButton`s (`NSWindowCloseButton` etc., aka "*Traffic Lights*") with code like the following:

```
NSButton *closeButton = [window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton];
[closeButton setFrame:newFrame];
[closeButton removeFromSuperview];
[window.contentView addSubview:closeButton];
```

The reposition works without problems. However, as soon as the window finished loading (became key), the tracking area was still at its old position (where those buttons were). Once I resized the window, the tracking area seemed to be updated to the correct (*current*) location.

I've tried things like `[closeButton updateTrackingAreas]`, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30417372/3642077) it shouldn't work anyways.

Are there more direct/correct ways to fix this issue without subclass `NSView`/`NSWindow`?

**Update:**

This is what I currently use to "fix" the issue: (via `NSWindowDelegate`)

```
- (void)windowDidBecomeMain:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSRect frame = [self.window frame];
    frame.size = NSMakeSize(frame.size.width, frame.size.height+1.f);
    [self.window setFrame:frame display:NO animate:NO];
    frame.size = NSMakeSize(frame.size.width, frame.size.height-1.f);
    [self.window setFrame:frame display:NO animate:YES];
}
```

The window will then be resized without refreshing the actual frame, to force update the tracking areas.